# Quoting identifiers for dynamic SQL in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

Is there a PL/SQL function or general technique to quote unqualified identifiers (e.g., `mytable`) for use in a dynamically constructed SQL query?  How about partially or fully qualified identifiers (`a.b@c`)?

Consider this contrived example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE by_the_numbers(COL_NAME VARCHAR, INTVAL INTEGER) IS
  ...
BEGIN
  -- COL_NAME is interpolated into SQL string
  -- INTVAL gets bound to :1
  stmt := 'SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ' || COL_NAME || ' = :1';
  ...
END
```

... where we don't want to permit naive SQL injection in `COL_NAME` (e.g., a value of '1=1 or 1').

Comment: Got example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @OMG Ponies, does that example clarify?  Basically I want an equivalent of the perl DBI's `quote_identifier()`

Comment: My experience is that you can't use a BIND variable for the column name, because being CHAR/VARCHAR it will automatically be enclosed in single quotes to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: @OMG, right.  The identifier must be *interpolated* (more or less), and so I'd like to quote it before doing that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is dbms_assert: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2.php for preventing sql injection.